# How can you make a leaflet map re-sizable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, leaflet

I have a `leaflet` map embedded in my page, but I want to add a control to allow the div with the leaflet map to be resized by the user. I've tried plugins like `jquery.ba-resize`, `twinhelix` and one other, but I can't seem to get something working that will allow me to have a button near the div with the leaflet map in it and to resize it on the fly.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found an easy answer, I just took the id of my map ('map', creative), and did

$('#map).resizable();

with a jquery-ui plugin on the page.

Good enough for what I wanted!